# filename in Antlr4.7 CharStreams.fromFileName()

Tags: java, file, directory, antlr, antlr4

I was trying to read the file named `test`. My program is `AntlrTest.java`. They are in the same directory: `/Users/MyName/Documents/`. The content in `AntlrTest.java` is shown below:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;

public class AntlrTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "test";
        CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(fileName);
    }
}
```

And what in the file `test` is just simple UTF-8 text `a//b`.

However, when I tried to `javac AntlrTest.java`, it says:

```
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(fileName);
                                                   ^
```

I also tried to change the filename to be an absolute path `/Users/MyName/Documents/test`, but just got the same IOException.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler shows the error and the possible solutions. Therefore, use one of the available alternatives:

1. Catch the `IOException` and handle it appropriately.

   ```
   try {
       CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(fileName);
   } catch (final IOException e) {
       // Handle the exception.
       // For example: log (print to standard to error) it and return.
       System.err.println(e);
       return;
   }
   ```
2. Declare the `IOException` to be thrown by the `main` method.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and the problem has gone! Thank you!

Comment: @paranoider, great! Glad it has helped. You are welcome!